# Screens flickers and resizes when starting video recording

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

I'm integrating photo/video capture in my app and am having an issue with video capture. Whenever video recording starts, the screen flickers, I get a short pause, then video capture begins. However, using the phone's camera app, there isn't a flicker/pause at all.

Also, my camera preview display gets resized as soon as `recorder.start()` is called. I don't see why that is. It makes the preview distorted (everything looks squished and wider).

My Questions: How do I prevent the flicker/pause when starting video recording? How do I prevent `recorder.start()` from resizing my preview display?

Whenever "video mode" is enabled, `initRecording()` is immediately called. Once the user presses a button, `startRecording()` is called. Finally, when the button is pressed again, `stopRecording()` is called. Less importantly, when switching back to "picture mode", `destroyRecorder()` is called.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera isn't available
        Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Camera is not available at this time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        getActivity().finish();
        return;
    }

    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD ) {
        setCameraDisplayOrientation( camera );
    }
    else {
        camera.setDisplayOrientation( 90 );
    }

    setCamera( camera );
    setCameraZoomDisplay( camera );

    if ( getSurfaceHolder() != null ) {
        startPreview();

        if ( getMode() == MODE_VIDEO ) {
            initRecording();
        }
    }
}

private void setCameraDisplayOrientation( Camera camera ) {

    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo( 0, info );

    int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result = ( info.orientation - degrees + 360 ) % 360;
    camera.setDisplayOrientation( result );
}

private void initRecording() {

    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    setRecorder( recorder );

    Camera camera = getCamera();
    camera.unlock();
    recorder.setCamera( camera );

    recorder.setAudioSource( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC );
    recorder.setVideoSource( MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA );

    CamcorderProfile cp = CamcorderProfile.get( CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH );
    recorder.setProfile( cp );

    String extension;
    switch (cp.fileFormat) {
        case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4:
            extension = "mp4";
            break;
        case MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP:
            extension = "3gp";
            break;
        default:
            extension = "tmp";
    }

    setVideoMimeType( MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension( extension ) );

    File toFile = new File( getActivity().getCacheDir(), "tempvideo.tmp" );
    if ( toFile.exists() ) {
        toFile.delete();
    }
    setTempFile( toFile );

    recorder.setOutputFile( toFile.getPath() );
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay( getSurfaceHolder().getSurface() );

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        setRecorderInitialized( true );
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean startRecording() {

    try {
        getRecorder().start();
        setRecording( true );

        ImageView actionImageView = getActionImageView();
        actionImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.record_red );
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        getCamera().lock();
    }

    return true;
}

private void stopRecording() {

    MediaRecorder recorder = getRecorder();
    if ( recorder != null && isRecording() ) {
        recorder.stop();
        setRecording( false );
        setRecorderInitialized( false );

        try {
            insertVideo();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        initRecording();

        ImageView actionImageView = getActionImageView();
        actionImageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.record_green );
    }
}

private void destroyRecorder() {

    MediaRecorder recorder = getRecorder();
    recorder.release();
    setRecorder( null );
    getCamera().lock();
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing the flicker and resize? I'm dealing with the same issue right now for a project I'm working on.

Comment: @MattDavis Sorry, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for the slight zoom when MediaRecorder.start() is invoked is due to the Camera resizing its preview to match the resolution of the video being recorded.  This problem can be fixed by setting the preview and video resoultion on setup.  I'm thinking I've also found a way to stop the flicker, although I've found that when working with Camera and MediaRecorder a little bit of lag or flicker can originate from any of a number of places, so that may be a bit tougher to track down.  [The Android documentation for setting up a camera/video recorder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) is a good place to start to ensure the main pieces are set up correctly, but I've found that it's necessary to delve into some of the class api documentation to debug and make the experience really smooth.

The `Camera.Parameters` class is the key to maintaining a smooth video recording experience.  Once you have a Camera object, you can use `Camera.getParameters()` to get the current parameters to modify them.  `Camera.setParameters(Camera.Parameters)` can then be used to trigger any changes that have been made.

To prevent the video resize, we need to ensure that the Parameters' preview size is in line with the video resolution to be recorded.  To get a list of supported Video/Preview sizes, we can use `Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()` on our current Parameters object, which will return a list of `Camera.Size` objects.  Each of these objects will have a width and height property, accessed directly via `Camera.Size.width` and `Camera.Size.height` (no getter methods).  The `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` method is [guaranteed to return at least one result,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29) and it seems as though the results are ordered from highest resolution to lowest.

(For API level > 11 there is also a `getSupportedVideoSizes()` method, but it seems like this is only if the device has some video sizes that are different from preview sizes, else it returns null.  I haven't had success with this method, so I'd stick with using PreviewSizes for now as it guarantees returning a size good for both video and preview, but it's something to be aware of going forward.)

Once we have the `Camera.Size` that corresponds to the video resolution we want, we can set that size using `Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height).`  Additionally, to help with the flicker, I use `Camera.Parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO).`  One these steps are taken, use `Camera.setParameters()` to notify the Camera of your changes.  I've had success setting these parameters once right after getting the camera, as setting parameters while the user is interacting with this Activity has caused some lag.  If you're using the same Activity for Video and Picture capture, you can also set picture parameters here, the Camera object will handle using the proper params for each mode.

Almost done!  Now that the preview is taken care of, all that's left is to ensure that the `MediaRecorder` uses the same resolution as the preview.  When preparing your media recorder, between the calls to `MediaRecorder.setProfile()` (or setting the encoders, for API Level < 8) and `MediaRecorder.setOutputFile()`, place a call to `MediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height)` using the same values as your preview.  Now, the transition from preview to record using `MediaRecorder.start()` should be seamless, as they're both using the same resolution.

Here're some quick code snippets so you can see everything in action:

Getting and setting the params:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

//myVideoSize is an instance of Camera.Size
List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
myVideoSize = previewSizes.get(0);
params.setPreviewSize(myVideoSize.width, myVideoSize.height);

camera.setParameters(params);
```

Then setting the size on the media recorder:

```
//After setting the profile....
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

//Use myVideoSize from above
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(myVideoSize.width, myVideoSize.height);

//Before setting the output file
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(myFile);
```

Comment: great post, thanks for explaining the entire process. I followed these steps but I'm still getting the resizing of the preview and the flickering. I'm setting the camera preview size and the `MediaRecorder`'s video size to the same values (640x480).

Comment: When i use this line. mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(myVideoSize.width, myVideoSize.height); Video is not recording in android.