# Background multiple record videos service with MediaRecorder

Tags: android, android-service, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I've used MediaRecorder in a background record video application. When record file is full, I change output file. When changing output file, I must stop MediaRecorder to prepare and start it again. But this make my preview Surface blink in a short of time.
Is there any solution for this ?

Start

```
public void start() {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(256 * 10000);    //2,560kb/s
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(CameraView.PREVIEW_WIDTH, CameraView.PREVIEW_HEIGHT);

        String fileName = mCommon.dateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmm", null) + ".mp4";
        File file = createInternalOutput(fileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());

        mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(VIDEO_FILESIZE);
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(VIDEO_DURATION);
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

On Info

```
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED || what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING) {
            boolean detectRecording = mCommon.getSettings(MainActivity.DETECT_RECORDING, false);
            stopRecord();
            start();
        }
    }
```

Stop

```
    public void stopRecord() {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mCamera.unlock();
        isRecording = false;
    }
```

Updated: I've found it. Because the size of preview surface and Layout in service is not the same. The answer is here [question]: [Screens flickers and resizes when starting video recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509197/screens-flickers-and-resizes-when-starting-video-recording)